# Why do I get a NullReferenceException in this MSpec test?

Tags: c#, mspec, ncrunch

So I have these nuget packages installed:

[image: Nuget]

Culminating in these references:

[image: References]

I use NCrunch. I have this spec:

```
namespace GlobPatternMatching.Tests
{
    using FluentAssertions;

    using Machine.Fakes;
    using Machine.Specifications;

    [Subject(typeof(GlobMatching))]
    public class When_Given_Literal : WithSubject<GlobMatching>
    {
        private static string pattern = "path";

        private static string[] result;

        private Establish context => () =>
            {
                pattern = "path";
            };

        private Because of => () => result = Subject.GetGlobs(pattern);

        private It should_return_path_in_the_array = () =>
            {
                result[0].Should().Be("path");
            };
    }
}
```

For this class:

```
namespace GlobPatternMatching
{
    using System;

    public class GlobMatching
    {
        public string[] GetGlobs(string pattern)
        {
            return pattern.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }
}
```

TDD'ing straight up, I get null reference exception. When I debug I can't step through the method, and all the spec class fields are null.....

I don't feel like I'm missing anything, but if you don't mind having a look and figuring what I've done wrong here that would be good. I'm using latest VS2015, NCrunch etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't believe what the issue was...

```
private Establish context => () =>
{
    pattern = "path";
};

private Because of => () => result = Subject.GetGlobs(pattern);
```

I've put `=>` instead of `=`....

```
// ----------------------\/-------
private Establish context = () =>
{
    pattern = "path";
};

// ----------------\/------------    
private Because of = () => result = Subject.GetGlobs(pattern);
```